# Offline Ascii art editor

Tags: software-recommendation, ascii-art

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and do not look for something like [Graph_Easy](https://github.com/ironcamel/Graph-Easy) which parses input, instead I look for some offline, free, [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) software that does tasks like what [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) does. For example these features are necessary:

- drawing multiple type of shapes (lines, arrows, rectangles) by dragging
- changing zoom level of page for drawing more longer/wider graphs
- typing text

[asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) provides a mean for resizing shapes, which is not necessary for me. Also it is better to be able to draw other shapes like circle. An open source software is appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [asciiflow](https://asciiflow.com/#/) provided a tool which can be launched locally. See the [installation](https://github.com/lewish/asciiflow#installation) section of GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

For **almost** real-time purposes (WYSIWYG) the best method I know is to use [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml) plugin for **GIMP** or **Krita**.You can install by running this:

```
sudo apt install gimp-gmic
```

Then in the GIMP window go to `Filters->G'MIC`.Then a window should pop up with almost 480 filters.Expand the **Arrays & tiles** and click on **Ascii art**.Then you should have something like this :

[image]

Draw in the canvas and then press the **Update** button.

If you want to get a output of it in a text file , then check the **Output ascii file** checkbox and after finishing your task press <kbd>Apply</kbd> :

[image]

And of course there are more options like setting the **charset**(e.g uppercase letters , math symbols) , synthesis scale , Gamma correction and so on.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some one has made a C++ version of ascii editor like the original asciiflow web version. See here: [schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT: QT Based Ascii Chart editor](https://github.com/schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT). This project can be build against either the QT GUI library or the wxWidgets GUI library.

I have just build one against the wxWidgets library, see the screen shots in this discussion here: [This project can be built with the wxWidget library? · Issue #4 · schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT](https://github.com/schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT/issues/4)